# Use type with implicit operator for EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class which encapsulates certain requirements for a string like this and uses the `implicit` operator:

```
class MyClass
{
    private string _value;

    public MyClass(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyClass cls)
    {
        return cls._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyClass(string value)
    {
        return new MyClass(value);
    }
}
```

How can I use this in EntityFramework Core to handle an attribute in a data model as a `string`?

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(12)]
    public MyClass Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to use `MyClass` as the primary key of the model which should be stored as a `string` with maximum length 12 in the database. Would be even better if I could skip the `MaxLength(12)` in some way or another.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)?

Comment: Can you see any error or unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Just to give this question an answer (yes, I know it's old)

Also, thanks to @jan-paolo-go for pointing me in the right direction

```cs
entity.Property(e => e.Id)
    .HasConversion(
        new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter<MyClass, string>(
            // Though not necessary I cast for clarity
            mC => (string)mC,
            v => (MyClass)v
        )
    );
```

The best thing about this is that you can stack them if you require different types to map back to the same property. You can also ***possibly*** *(not tested yet)* throw an exception if don't want to save the property to the DB (as below)

```cs
aw => (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<byte[]>>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(typeof(Exception))).Compile())(),
```